# Linker errors: referenced in function _main

Tags: c++, linker

I am getting some linker errors when I try to compile my program with a template:

GCD.h

```
#include <iostream> // allows program to perform input and output 
using namespace std; // program uses names from the std namespace 

template <class T> class GCD {
   public:
      T gcd(T x, T y);  
};

// gcd finds greatest common divisor of x and y
template <class T>
T gcd(T x, T y) {
   T greatest = 1; // current greatest common divisor, 1 is minimum

   // loop from 2 to smaller of x and y
   for ( T i = 2; i <= ( ( x < y ) ? x: y ); i++ )
   {
      // if current i divides both x and y
      if ( x % i == 0 && y % i == 0 )
     {
         greatest = i; // update greatest common divisor
     }
   } // end for

   return greatest; // return greatest common divisor found
} // end template function gcd
```

I'm getting these linker errors but I'm not sure what they mean:

```
1>Fraction.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Fraction::Fraction(__int64,__int64)" (??0Fraction@@QAE@_J0@Z) referenced in function "public: class Fraction __thiscall Fraction::negate(void)const " (?negate@Fraction@@QBE?AV1@XZ)
1>MainProg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Fraction::Fraction(__int64,__int64)" (??0Fraction@@QAE@_J0@Z)
1>MainProg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Fraction::Fraction(void)" (??0Fraction@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main\
```

I have the template definition at the top so I'm not sure what the problem is.

This is my MainProg.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include "Fraction.h" // include definition of class Fraction from Fraction.h
#include "GCD.h"      // include definition of gcd template function

int main()
{
    // Test constructors

    Fraction A; // create a Fraction object with default ctor
    cout << "The default object is: ";
    A.display();

    Fraction B(1,1024); // create a Fraction object with the non-default ctor
    cout << "\n\nThe non-default object is: ";
    B.display();

    Fraction C(8,-1024); // test to see if the simplify method is invoked from 
                                    //   the non-default ctor
    cout << "\n\n8/-1024 simplified is: ";
    C.display();

    // Test template gcd() function

    // implicitly invoke template function

    int intX = 1024;
    int intY = 32;

    int intAns = gcd(intX,intY); // implicit invocation
    cout << "\n\nThe greatest common divisor of 1024 and 32 is: " << intAns;

    // explicitly invoke template function

    long longX = 1024;
    long longY = 1048576;

    long longAns = gcd<long>(longX, longY); // explicit invocation
    cout << "\n\nThe greatest common divisor of 1024 and 1048576 is: " << longAns;

    // Test timesEq()
    cout << "\n\n- Test timesEq()";
    A = Fraction(2,3); //Assign new values to Fraction objects
    B = Fraction(3,5);

    // Output "before" values
    cout << "\nA = ";
    A.display();
    cout << "\nB = ";
    B.display();

    // NOTE: Equivalent to:  C = A *= B;
    C = A.timesEq(B);

    // Output "after" values
    cout << "\n\nA = ";
    A.display();
    cout << "\nB = ";
    B.display();
    cout << "\nC = ";
    C.display();

    // Test divideEq()
    cout << "\n\n- Test divideEq()";
    A = Fraction(2,3);  //Assign new values to Fraction objects
    B = Fraction(-7,3);

    // Output "before" values
    cout << "\nA = ";
    A.display();
    cout << "\nB = ";
    B.display();

    // NOTE: Equivalent to:  C = A /= B;
    C = A.divideEq(B);

    // Output "after" values
    cout << "\n\nA = ";
    A.display();
    cout << "\nB = ";
    B.display();
    cout << "\nC = ";
    C.display();

    // Test plusEq()
    cout << "\n\n- Test plusEq()";
    A = Fraction(-5,-6);  //Assign new values to Fraction objects
    B = Fraction(9,10);

    // Output "before" values
    cout << "\nA = ";
    A.display();
    cout << "\nB = ";
    B.display();

    // NOTE: Equivalent to:  C = A += B;
    C = A.plusEq(B);

    // Output "after" values
    cout << "\n\nA = ";
    A.display();
    cout << "\nB = ";
    B.display();
    cout << "\nC = ";
    C.display();

    // Test minusEq()
    cout << "\n\n- Test minusEq()";
    A = Fraction(2,3);  //Assign new values to Fraction objects
    B = Fraction(8,9);

    // Output "before" values
    cout << "\nA = ";
    A.display();
    cout << "\nB = ";
    B.display();

    // NOTE: Equivalent to:  C = A -= B;
    C = A.minusEq(B);

    // Output "after" values
    cout << "\n\nA = ";
    A.display();
    cout << "\nB = ";
    B.display();
    cout << "\nC = ";
    C.display();

    // Test negate()
    cout << "\n\n- Test negateEq()";
    A = Fraction(-2,3);  //Assign new values to Fraction objects
    B = Fraction(8,9);

    // Output "before" values
    cout << "\nA = ";
    A.display();
    cout << "\nB = ";
    B.display();

    // NOTE: Equivalent to:  C = -A;
    C = A.negate();

    // Output "after" values
    cout << "\n\nA = ";
    A.display();
    cout << "\nC = ";
    C.display();

    // Output "before" values
    cout << "\n\nB = ";
    B.display();
    cout << "\nC = ";
    C.display();

    // NOTE: Equivalent to:  C = -B;
    C = B.negate();

    // Output "after" values
    cout << "\n\nB = ";
    B.display();
    cout << "\nC = ";
    C.display();

    cout << '\n' << endl;

    return 0;

} // end main
```

And Fraction.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Fraction.h"
#include "GCD.h" // template function for calculating greatest common divisor

//Implementation of the timesEq() member function
//Performs similar operation as the *= operator on the built-in types
const Fraction & Fraction::timesEq(const Fraction & op )
{
    numerator *= op.numerator;
    denominator *= op.denominator;

    simplify();  // will make sure that denominator is positive and
                 //   will invoke gcd() function to reduce fraction
                 //   as much as possible

    return (*this); // returns the object which invoked the method
}

const Fraction & Fraction::plusEq (const Fraction & op )
{
    numerator *= op.denominator;
    numerator += op.numerator * denominator;
    denominator *= op.denominator;

    simplify();  // will make sure that denominator is positive and
                 //   will invoke gcd() function to reduce fraction
                 //   as much as possible

    return (*this); // returns the object which invoked the method
}

const Fraction & Fraction::minusEq (const Fraction & op )
{
    numerator *= op.denominator;
    denominator = denominator * op.denominator;
    numerator -= op.numerator;

    simplify();  // will make sure that denominator is positive and
                 //   will invoke gcd() function to reduce fraction
                 //   as much as possible

    return (*this); // returns the object which invoked the method
}

const Fraction & Fraction::divideEq (const Fraction & op )
{
    numerator *= op.denominator;
    denominator *= op.numerator;

    simplify();  // will make sure that denominator is positive and
                 //   will invoke gcd() function to reduce fraction
                 //   as much as possible

    return (*this); // returns the object which invoked the method
}

Fraction Fraction::negate(void) const
{
    return Fraction((-1 * numerator), denominator);
}

void Fraction::display(void)const {
    cout << numerator << "/" << denominator;
}

void Fraction::simplify(void)
{
    numerator /= gcd(numerator, denominator);
    denominator /= gcd(numerator, denominator);
}
```

Fraction.h:

```
#ifndef Fraction_incl
#define Fraction_incl

class Fraction  // Fraction class
{
public:
    Fraction (void); // default ctor
    Fraction (long long num, long long denom = 1 );  // second ctor, which
       // requires at least one long long argument

    const Fraction & plusEq (const Fraction & RHS ) ; //Adds RHS to the Fraction object invoked with this method
                                          //  (thereby modifying the Fraction object) and returns the result
    const Fraction & minusEq (const Fraction & RHS ) ; //Subtracts RHS from the Fraction object invoked with this method
                                          //  (thereby modifying the Fraction object) and returns the result
    const Fraction & timesEq (const Fraction & RHS ) ; //Multiplies RHS by the Fraction object invoked with this method
                                          //  (thereby modifying the Fraction object) and returns the result
    const Fraction & divideEq (const Fraction & RHS ) ; //Divides RHS into the Fraction object invoked with this method
                                          //  (thereby modifying the Fraction object) and returns the result

    Fraction negate (void)const; //Returns the negation of the Fraction object
                            //  invoked with the method but must NOT
                            //  modify the actual Fraction object invoked
                            //  with the method.

    long long getNum(void)const;   // Returns numerator
    long long getDenom(void)const; // Returns denominator

    void display(void)const; // Outputs to standard output stream the Fraction object
                        //   in the format: numerator/denominator

private:

    void simplify (void); // this method reduces the Fraction objects as much
                          //  as possible.  It also ensures that the denominator is
                          //  positive.
    long long numerator, // represents numerator of Fraction object
        denominator;     // represents denominator of Fraction object

};
#endif
```

Comment: The code you have posted does not appear to be related to the error messages you are getting. It looks like you have some other files, likely named MainProg.cpp and Fraction.cpp, and probably a Fraction.h as well. You're going to need to show us these.

Comment: Where is the `Fraction` class?

Comment: Where is fraction.h?  That will be key since it presumably holds the declaration of `Fraction` that `main` sees.

Comment: @CareyGregory I added Fraction.h just now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem as if you ever provide a function definition for these guys:

```
public:
    Fraction (void); // default ctor
    Fraction (long long num, long long denom = 1 );
```

so naturally the linker cannot find them. You want something like:

```
Fraction::Fraction(void) : numerator(0), denominator(1) {}
Fraction::Fraction(long long num, long long denom) :
                     numerator(num), denominator(denom) {
    if ( denom == 0 ) {
        throw "denominator cannot be zero";  // Or other exception
    }
}
```

in `Fraction.cpp`.

Comment: Thanks it compiles now; how do I make it so the default constructor can't have a denominator of 0?

Comment: @theintellects: Hah, good point. Just change the `0` to something else, I edited. If you want to make sure the other constructor won't accept a denominator of 0, then the normal way would be to check the value of `denom` in the body of the function, and throw an exception if it's `0`.